# How to get my div to fade out with jQuery on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm brand new to jQuery (and javascript in general). I've been meaning to use it/learn it for some time, and nows the time.

So I'm going to use jQuery [on this page](http://joelglovier.com) to fade out the "under construction" warning at the top of the page on load. But I'm unfamiliar with any of the functions or selectors to use.

I found [this basic article](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) at jQuery which has a demo that seems to work perfect for what I'm doing, only it's set up to fade out on click.

What do I need to change to get it to fade out after a few seconds once the page has loaded, and can you point me where to look to find out more about those type of functions (specifically on jQuery's site, if you're familiar). And please don't say, "In the documentation." I'm a noob but not a dummy, thanks. I'm just trying to learn more about that particular area of the syntax responsible for functions for now (if that's what they're called).

Comment: Dude, I love the site. Love the shadow on the text. Love the unique idea, and love the homage to JC in the CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words man!

Comment: Just a suggestion:

If you add some styling to your "under construction" div. You can keep your page from sliding up when your div fades out. 

Something like "<div id="tempwarning" style="z-index:100;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px; width:100%;">" should work.

Comment: PS: http://jagboards.com/ is a broken link on your website. ;-)

Comment: @Brandon - great suggestion. Thanks!

@rockinthesixstring, thanks for the heads up. I was switching the domain from GoDaddy to Bluehost and must have forgot all about setting the forwarders up again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   window.setTimeout("fadeMyDiv();", 3000); //call fade in 3 seconds
 }
)

function fadeMyDiv() {
   $("#myDiv").fadeOut('slow');
}
```

Comment: Couldn't get it to work - and not sure which parts of this to replace with my actual id. Just this piece?
$("#tempwarning")

Comment: Yes, if tempwarning is the ID attribute of the div you want to fade.

Comment: OK, working now. I think I had an error in my link to the jQuery library.

Comment: BTW, how do I know where to place my scripts? It seems like some belong in the head, and some right before the ending body tag?

Comment: Scripts load one at a time. Since you're using the $(document).ready, then you can put your scripts at the end (in this case). Just make sure that the jquery library is placed before your function. A good rule of thumb is to actually try and get as much of your scripts at the bottom as possible.

Answer (score 8):

New to jQuery 1.4 is the [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) method. Using it for this purpose:

```
$("#myDiv").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
```

Comment: Awesome, taught me something new!

Answer (score 2):

Hey, the site looks cool.  This should do it for you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(fade, 2000);
}

function fade(){
   $("#tempwarning").fadeOut(1000);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I think I might have had an error in my link to the jQuery library. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No problem.  You may want to check into firebug, or firebug lite.  ;)

Comment: I might also suggest that you use a specific version from the Google API CDN : http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete example.

Just paste this into an html file and save it.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" />
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        window.setTimeout('fadeout();', 3000);
    });

    function fadeout(){
        $('#tempwarning').fadeOut('slow', function() {
           // Animation complete.
        });
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tempwarning">

        <div class="wrap">

            <span class="warning-icon">!</span>

            <p>
                Oops! Please pardon my appearance. I'm still <a href="http://graphicriver.net/item/under-construction-graphic/53758?ref=jglovier">under development</a>. Please visit often.
            </p>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

This line of code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { });
```

Waits for the page to load before executing anything inside it.

Comment: Very true, I missed that part in the question. Great answer by the way!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ $("#tempwarning").fadeOut(); }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: This won't pause for a few seconds before fading out as specified by the OP

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
    window.setTimeout('fadeout();', 1000);
});

function fadeout(){
    $('.loader').fadeOut('fast', function() {
       // Animation complete.
    });
}

</script>
```

---

Perfect for a LoadingPage